# How to display the Month in fully in JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm using JSTL to format the `Java Date object` to display a date in the format like

`September 29, 2015 11:28 AM`

I tried below approach ,

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern="MMMMMMMM d,yyyy HH:mm a" value="${response.date}" />
```

I wonder how many `M`'s I need here. I mean I put 8 M s  in a wild guess.

Comment: Have you tried `dateStyle="long" timeStyle="long"`. It will give you the following output : `29 September 2015 11:28:00`

Comment: Yeah. But the required format is as in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSTL `<fmt:formatDate>` uses `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` under the covers.

So, just read its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) how to use the pattern syntax.

> Pattern letters are usually repeated, as their number determines the exact presentation:
>
> - Text: For formatting, **if the number of pattern letters is 4 or more, the full form is used**; otherwise a short or abbreviated form is used if available.

So, 4 letters as in `MMMM` is sufficient to represent the full form.